# making subfolder unrestricted while using .htpasswd in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have multiple applications running in my linux server.

The main domain is secure using .htpasswd file.

But I need the security to be removed in the subdomain.

How could I achieve this.

Regards

Nizam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following in a .htaccess file inside the subfolder:

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from All
Satisfy any
```

`Order deny,allow` causes `Allow` to override any `Deny` directives.
`Allow from All` grants access to all hosts.
`Satisfy any` causes the password authentication to be bypassed because a host-based rule (`Allow from All`) was passed.

Links to the Apache manual:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#satisfy

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation