# Remove .htpasswd Password Protection .(Nginx)

Tags: linux, .htaccess, security, nginx, .htpasswd

I added an htpasswd.txt to sites-avaiable/default to protect my site:

```
server {
        auth_basic "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file /tmp/.htpasswd.txt;

        listen 81 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/path/to/root
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name ipaddress;
```

Now that i'm trying to remove it, I can't get rid of a .htpasswd protection I set up previously. I've tried everything from creating .htaccess in the root of my site with satisfy any [like this post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519088/overriding-global-htpasswd-password-protection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863994/making-subfolder-unrestricted-while-using-htpasswd-in-apache), to deleting the reference to htpasswd.txt from my sites-available/default file, to reinstalling nginx. I can't find where this htpasswd file is being referenced somewhere from because nothing seems to get rid of it. Lastly I tried deleted the htpasswd.txt file and that just broke the login.

I want the whole site to be available with no htpasswd.

I also did a grep search to find out if the htpasswd file is being called for and it's no where to be found. What can I do?

Comment: I should add that I also tried deleted the htpasswd file and it's reference in the server block

Comment: You already asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688065/remove-password-protection-htaccess-nginx).

Comment: @mikerockett   yes I did. Still haven't found an answer and am getting no responses. Any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't mean that you should ask it again. If there are no responses, it means that those who have viewed it are unable to help you. Per [this recommendation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278511/1626250), I'm afraid I'm going to have vote to close this as a duplicate. I can only recommend that you add the additional information (such as your code) from this question to the original question.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to assist if you can. @mikerockett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion to anyone with a problem such as this involving unknowns that cannot be dealt with after much effort: Go to your Server (in my case digital ocean) and create a new (take a snapshot of your server to apply to your new IP) IP / droplet for your site. Uninstall your server engine (Nginx or Apache) and reinstall on the new server / IP. It's a little annoying but at least you wont be stuck like I was for days. Thats how I fixed it. Also, don't despair, you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

That file is a hidden file within the /tmp directory to view all hidden files in that directory go to:

> /tmp

Then do the command

> ls -al

This will show all hidden files in that folder along with permissions.

To remove that file do:

> rm -rf .htpasswd.txt

The little . in front of a file means that it is a hidden file and the flag to view hidden files is ls -a

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've been able to find and delete the file.  The problem is deleting it doesn't remove the password auth window.

Comment: Oh now i see, i thought you just meant that you couldnt find the file.

Try the following:

find / -name auth_basic_user_file 
find /-name .htpasswd.txt

And see if they are referenced anywhere else as there may be a chance that a copy has been made somehow and it is actually referencing somehwere else

Comment: good thinking. Nah its not. I also searched for any mention of auth_basic etc. Heres a question: I completely reinstalled nginx after a uninstall purge but the password lock stayed. Is there some other high level way I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Im guessing youv tried rebooting the server? When you uninstalled nginx and reinstalled did all the config files stay the same? The only thing I can think of would maybe delete all the config files, making copies of the necessary ones on a notepad for now then uninstalling so it gets all frsh configs and that might heklp fix it. Apart from that im not too sure

Comment: yea I was hoping that would work when I did the purge. All of the files were deleted but no change. Thanks for your help sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is most likely caching the required auth.  Try a different browser or clear your browser cache.